# Sorting deeply nested objects in an Array using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I'm fairly new to working with arrays and objects.
I have the array below that contains multiple objects and those objects contain 1 object called date and 1 nested array called data ( data contains 2 keys, date and expense )

I'm able to map over the array to output what I want.

**Problem:**
I cannot figure out how to sort the array alphabetically from A to Z without destructuring it.
I know I should use probably something like this function for the sorting but since it's deeply nested, I cannot seem to properly hit a.expense.

```
.sort((a, b) => (a.expense > b.expense ? -1 : 1))
```

**What I currently have going on:**
Lets assume the array is called arr

```
      {arr.map((item) => {
              return item.data
                .map((d) => (
                  <div>
                    <div>{d.expense}</div> <div>{d.date}</div>
                  </div>
                )).sort((a, b) => (a.expense > b.expense ? -1 : 1)) // sorting doesnt work
      })}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the expected sorting order?

Comment: sorry my bad, just updated the question. Alphabetically from A to Z

Comment: You need to sort the data before you map it to JSX: `return item.data.sort(...).map((d) => ...);`

Comment: you mean sort the array before I map over it the first time or the second time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mapping your data to JSX and then trying to sort it. You need to sort it *before* you map it to jsx:

```
      {arr.map((item) => {
              return item.data
                // sort first, then render
                .sort((a, b) => (a.expense > b.expense ? -1 : 1))
                .map((d) => (
                  <div>
                    <div>{d.expense}</div> <div>{d.date}</div>
                  </div>
                ))
      })}
```

But please know that this will sort your data on every render, which is a bit of a resource hog. It's possible for your component to render multiple times without the data changing. You are better off sorting the data on the server (in your db call/query), or immediately after you load the data:

```
fetch(...)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.sort(...))
```